# Retrieve all tables and views name with schema name from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the sql query to retrieve all tables and views name with its schema name from SQL server.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you search for a solution?

Comment: Ok, What did you try to retrieve all tables and views name with its schema name from SQL server?

Comment: This is in the [System Catalog FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/querying-the-sql-server-system-catalog-faq), along with a bunch of related common tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, though it would have been rather easy to find out:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE [TABLE_TYPE] IN('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW');
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be ok with this:

```
SELECT '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'
AS SchemaTable
FROM sys.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sys.Objects` and `Sys.Schemas` as

```
SELECT O.name ObjectName,
       S.name SchemaName,
       CASE O.type WHEN 'U' THEN 'TABLE'
                   WHEN 'V' THEN 'VIEW'
       END ObjectType

FROM Sys.Objects O INNER JOIN Sys.Schemas S
     ON O.schema_id = S.schema_id
WHERE O.type = 'U'
      OR
      O.type = 'V'
--    AND 
--    S.name = 'dbo' if you want a specific schema
```

Here is an **[example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=693829e8f515efead79874b9d86b6ac7)**

Comment: Side note. You could simple use `WHERE O.type IN ('U', 'V')` otherwise you have to use brackets in following `(O.type = 'U'
      OR
      O.type = 'V') AND S.name = 'dbo'`